# Non-homogenous recurrences using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'd like to practice solving non-homogenous recurrences using ordinary generating functions. Consider an example
$$
a_n = a_{n-2} + 2 a_{n-1} -3 + 2^n \quad (n>2)
$$
with $a_0 = 1, a_2 = 2$. In particular, $a_1 = -1$.
Let $F(x)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be the associated generating function. Solving this for the homogenous part is routine, if I am not mistaken, the sequence $(a_n)$ is like this:
$$
1,4,4,-8,16,-32, \ldots
$$
so the pattern is clear. Can one tell me how to write it concisely to incorporate the non-homogenous part? More generally, how to approach such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

After multiplying by $x^n$ we have

$$
a_nx^n - a_{n-2}x^n - 2 a_{n-1}x^n + 3x^n - 2^nx^n=0
$$

and summing up

$$
S(x) -x^2S(x)-2xS(x)+\frac{3}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1-2x}=\phi_0(x)
$$

or

$$
S(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2-2x}\left(\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{3}{1-x}+\phi_0(x)\right)
$$

here $\phi_0(x)$ contains the initial conditions. Also

$$
x^2+2x-1 = (x+1)^2-2 = (x+1-\sqrt{2})(x+1+\sqrt{2})
$$

$$
\phi_0(x) = -(a_0+a_1x)+2(a_1x)=a_1 x-a_0
$$

NOTE

This recurrence needs only two initial conditions.